# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.whatsappclone.User

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

I am not able to retrieve data from Firebase it always crashes saying:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object
> of type java.lang.String to type com.example.whatsappclone.User

This is My Model Class

```
public class User {

String uid, name, phoneNumber, profileImage;

public User()
{

}

public User(String uid, String name, String phoneNumber, String profileImage) {
    this.uid = uid;
    this.name = name;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.profileImage = profileImage;
}

public String getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public void setUid(String uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

public String getProfileImage() {
    return profileImage;
}

public void setProfileImage(String profileImage) {
    this.profileImage = profileImage;
}
```

}

This is My ViewHolder Class

```
public class UsersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UsersAdapter.UsersViewHolder> {


Context context;
ArrayList<User> users;
public UsersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<User>users) {
    this.context = context;
    this.users = users;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public UsersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.conversation_layout, parent, false);

    return new UsersViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UsersViewHolder holder, int position) {

    User user = users.get(position);
    holder.binding.userName.setText(user.getName());

    Glide.with(context).load(user.getProfileImage())
            .into(holder.binding.profile);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return users.size();
}

public class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ConversationLayoutBinding binding;

    public UsersViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        binding = ConversationLayoutBinding.bind(itemView);
    }
}
```

}

This is My MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ActivityMainBinding binding;
FirebaseDatabase database;
ArrayList<User> users;
UsersAdapter usersAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    users = new ArrayList<>();

    usersAdapter = new UsersAdapter(this, users);
    binding.recyclerView.setAdapter(usersAdapter);

    database.getReference().child("users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            users.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren())
            {
                User user = snapshot1.getValue(User.class);
                users.add(user);

            }
            usersAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

My Firebase database Structured

[Firebase Database Strucuture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFxy7.png)

Firebase JSON

```
{ "users" : {
"A5DEg64d47StvLuvRtLWiu1bHSC3" : {
  "name" : "Rahul Singh",
  "phoneNumber" : "+918350877517",
  "profileImage" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/whatsapp-clone-b908d.appspot.com/o/Profiles%2FA5DEg64d47StvLuvRtLWiu1bHSC3?alt=media&token=55fcdc75-da0c-43f5-8f9c-44bfa7df500f",
  "uid" : "A5DEg64d47StvLuvRtLWiu1bHSC3"
},
"CO6Yw59BHweNJ03UdbcsGq4kyXY2" : {
  "name" : "Alok Bhai",
  "phoneNumber" : "+919886542409",
  "profileImage" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/whatsapp-clone-b908d.appspot.com/o/Profiles%2FCO6Yw59BHweNJ03UdbcsGq4kyXY2?alt=media&token=b006e40d-e8df-4b96-9165-d980cd018af3",
  "uid" : "CO6Yw59BHweNJ03UdbcsGq4kyXY2"
},
"F8mhqJk4POeLFWxpF373K2D8DYG2" : {
  "name" : "radhe govind'",
  "phoneNumber" : "+916378757808",
  "profileImage" : "No Image",
  "uid" : "F8mhqJk4POeLFWxpF373K2D8DYG2"
},
"NOt57HC59DZm1s5XaBk0mHb9H553" : {
  "name" : "Mohit Dada",
  "phoneNumber" : "+917853471027",
  "profileImage" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/whatsapp-clone-b908d.appspot.com/o/Profiles%2FNOt57HC59DZm1s5XaBk0mHb9H553?alt=media&token=6aba255c-5f96-4ba1-a4a4-b998d3ae5b4a",
  "uid" : "NOt57HC59DZm1s5XaBk0mHb9H553"
},
"XnJUq8LzauZPCLCi5v4SeCGgSPa2" : {
  "name" : "Alok Singh Deshwal",
  "phoneNumber" : "+919960726182",
  "profileImage" : "No Image",
  "uid" : "XnJUq8LzauZPCLCi5v4SeCGgSPa2"
},
"ZIcwyjMGC3Yk5GrT7vIeTxphQPt2" : {
  "name" : "Anku Bhai",
  "phoneNumber" : "+919094974311",
  "profileImage" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/whatsapp-clone-b908d.appspot.com/o/Profiles%2FZIcwyjMGC3Yk5GrT7vIeTxphQPt2?alt=media&token=5773be33-d610-4f8d-8bbd-d655e5228666",
  "uid" : "ZIcwyjMGC3Yk5GrT7vIeTxphQPt2"
},
"kE3i5DsP9DTorG5DkJ4Vy7nArwZ2" : {
  "name" : "Prinshu",
  "phoneNumber" : "+91989600555",
  "profileImage" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/whatsapp-clone-b908d.appspot.com/o/Profiles%2FkE3i5DsP9DTorG5DkJ4Vy7nArwZ2?alt=media&token=e4d13d95-3906-4bdf-aaac-028816e490d5",
  "uid" : "kE3i5DsP9DTorG5DkJ4Vy7nArwZ2"
},
"name" : "Vivek Fauzdar",
"phoneNumber" : "+916486627517",
"profileImage" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/whatsapp-clone-b908d.appspot.com/o/Profiles%2FA5DEg64d47StvLuvRtLWiu1bHSC3?alt=media&token=cf8613fb-ae66-4892-bd79-4affa89d86e4",
"uid" : "A5DEg64d47StvLuvRtLWiu1bHSC3",
"vYfKxxkvoCV0p4c4P64t3F1IrEn1" : {
  "name" : "Om Swami",
  "phoneNumber" : "+919887012345",
  "profileImage" : "No Image",
  "uid" : "vYfKxxkvoCV0p4c4P64t3F1IrEn1"
}
```

}
}

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: the app is crashing at com.example.whatsappclone.MainActivity$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:46) which is                 
User user = snapshot1.getValue(User.class);

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Please Check Sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.whatsappclone.User

Because under your "users" there aren't only User objects, there are also strings:

```
"name" : "Vivek Fauzdar",
"phoneNumber" : "+916486627517",
"profileImage" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/whatsapp-clone-b908d.appspot.com/o/Profiles%2FA5DEg64d47StvLuvRtLWiu1bHSC3?alt=media&token=cf8613fb-ae66-4892-bd79-4affa89d86e4",
"uid" : "A5DEg64d47StvLuvRtLWiu1bHSC3",
```

When you are using the following line of code:

```
User user = snapshot1.getValue(User.class);
```

It means that you are trying to map each child into an object of type `User`, which isn't possible since you are mixing `User` objects with strings, hence that error. The simplest solution would be to remove all those strings and make sure you have only `User` objects under the "users" node. The code looks good to me.

See, all these children exist right under the "users" node.

Comment: sir sorry I m a beginner and  I did not get it completely, can u further explain please

Comment: Have you tried to remove those 4 **String** values that exist at the bottom of your JSON file? Does it work after you delete them?

Comment: no sir it is not working

Comment: It's really hard to help with "it is not working". What exactly didn't work? Please export the changed JSON file and add it to your question to see that those 5 strings are gone.

Comment: sir, i have to remove those strings from User.class file???

Comment: No, from the Database. Open the Firebase console and remove them.

Comment: Have you removed the those four strings from the database?

Comment: sir should i delete them?

Comment: Sir I have deleted them from firebase.

Comment: Perfect, does it work right now?

Comment: it is working sir but i did not get it why it is working now and not before??

Comment: Once you have only User objects and **not** strings, all children will be mapped successfully.

Answer (score 0):

if `"users"` is first layer of database children it will be a reference
instead of

```
database.getReference().child("users").addValueEventListener ...
```

use

```
database.getReference("users").addValueEventListener ...
```

if `"users"` is a child or an upper reference

```
database.getReference("upperReference").child("users").addValueEventListener ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is occurring because there is a requirement to transform your data into a Firebase node. I have coded the same in java ,and it is working fine

This should be your firebase  hierarchy
[Check this image  , in this under the user child we have one another key which is your uID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5Za0.png)

The error you're encountering will be resolved when you update the current code with the following modification:

```java
database
    .getReference()
    .child("users")
    .child(uid)
    .setValue(user)
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
            Intent intent= new Intent(SetUpProfileActivity.this,ActivityMainChat.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
});
```

Make sure you add `.child(uid)`

```java
database.getReference().child("users").child(uid).setValue(user)...
```